# Listing all shared folders on Windows 7 from Windows XP takes long time

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, network-shares, shared-folders

I have 22 shared folders on a Windows 7 Professional x64 server. When I list them from Windows XP by browsing `\\SERVER\` it takes about 30 seconds to finish. If I do the same under Windows 7 or Vista the listing finishes immediately. What could cause the long delay when accessing from Windows XP? If I acces shared folders directly by `\\SERVER\sharedfolder` I have no delay problems, only when I try to list all shared folders.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the SERVER using their ip address? \\x.x.x.x\sharedfolder ? Usually the slow down is caused by the time windows need to resolve the SERVER name into an IP address. If it is still slow using IP address, then something else is wrong.

Comment: Read it again. I have no problems when accessing directly. Only If I browse \\SERVER\ to list all shares it takes long time. There is no difference if I browse it by server IP \\x.x.x.x\

Comment: This could simply be due to the hardware differences and/or the optimization of Windows itself.